# How do we manage rabbitmq configuration for multiple applications

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue

Currently, we use the following approach when managing application configuration for rabbitmq:

- We build a basic rabbitmq cluster using Ansible.
- Then, we have 20+ products, each of which depends on RabbitMQ, and each will have different requirements for producing and consuming of messages.
  Each application has a json file that describes each exchange/queue/binding required for the application (e.g. rabbitmq.json), we generate the exchanges/queues/bindings in a pre-defined way (see below)
  Each application registers producers and consumers it requires
  Each application also creates queues live only for the duration of the application running (this type of queue is only required by a few applications)

This question I have is around the generation of exchanges, queues and bindings that life beyond the lifecycle of the application.
Currently, we set up these queues outside the applications themselves in a pre-defined way i.e:

- Create a json file per application that describes each exchange/queue/binding required for the application (e.g. rabbitmq.json)
- We wrote a script that then traverses through all application rabbitmq.json files and generates a new single Powershell script (e.g. generate_queues_exchanges_bindings.ps1) that contains all exchange/queue and binding we management api calls (executable via curl)
- We then execute curl commands generated in this generate_queues_exchanges_bindings.ps1 script

Recently however, we have been looking at this area. Some of us are proposing to use the fluent interface per application (on startup) to generate all exchanges/queues/bindings etc. This of course should work as all of these commands are idempotent in nature.
Others do not want to go down the road of configuring all of these queues, exchanges and bindings in our application and want to pre-define the configuration in advance.

What is the correct/recommended approach?, should we be pre-configuring our rabbitmq queues/exchanges/bindings or should each application be responsible (on startup) for ensuring these queues/exchanges/bindings are created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintenance will be easier if your applications ensure the resources they need are available when they start (or as they run). If you save resources in definitions files they will get out of sync with your applications and may not even be in source control.

My $0.02